# How to test protect_from_forgery with: :exception rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I am using `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in my application. It seems to work fine but I want to test it.

I have a form. I understand that every form has a authenticity token related with it while using `protect_from_forgery`, I want to create a situation when the authenticity token does not pass and throws an exception. I want to see how the browser will respond with the exception.

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: this is an out of the box feature provided with Rails - it is already tested. You don't have to test such things.

Comment: The reason I want to test it is to see how the browser will respond to it. Is there any work around to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this:

- The authenticity token is part of the form data: edit page to alter / remove these and form submission should result in an exception. Ajax submitted forms can also csrf meta tags in the `head` portion of the page - you may wish to alter these to.
- Create a standalone html page (outside of your app) which contains a form posting to the action you want to test
- The authenticity token is stored in the session, so after the form has been displayed hit a url in another browser tab / session that calls `reset_session`. Now submit the form - it should fail.